# 2 images. change only on hover not on mouseout

Tags: jquery, hover

Using jQuery, I've been able to swap images on hover and change it back on mouseout.

I have 2 images, image1 and image2. image1 is the original image, when hovered mouse2 should be shown and should remain even on mouseout. on the next hover, the original image replaces image2 and so on...

I've tried 2 codes. The first one changes the image back on mouseout. The second one, nothing happens even on initial hover.

Code 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img1").hover(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image1.jpg') {
            $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image2.jpg');
        } else if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image1.jpg') {
            $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image1.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Code 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img1").hover(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image1.jpg') {
            $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image2.jpg');
        }
        if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image1.jpg') {
            $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image1.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use the `.hover()` shortcut, just bind the `mouseenter` event like `$('#img1').on('mouseenter', function() { ... })`

Comment: In your 'else if' you are regarding to the same url as in your if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#img1").on('mouseenter', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image1.jpg') {
        $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image2.jpg');
    } else if ($(this).attr('src') == 'www.domain.com/image2.jpg') {
        $(this).attr('src','www.domain.com/image1.jpg');
    }
});
```

As per my comment, you do not have use the `.hover()` shortcut, just bind the `mouseenter` event.

Edit: I also fixed the `else if` part, but I leave the code optimization to you.

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helped you feel free to upvote it and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: i will. stackoverflow tells me to wait for 2 more minutes to do that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation clearly states, the `hover` function adds a handler to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

If you only want to handle `mouseenter`, don't do that.